# How to catch activated command from child component to parent component in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, command

I've got a MainWindow that contains a main menu. The menu is a UserControl, consisting of a StackPanel with Buttons inside.

The simplified XAML code is as follows:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:MainMenu Grid.Column="0"></local:MainMenu> <!-- the navigation menu -->

        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

<!-- The navigation menu UserControl -->
<UserControl Class="MyApp.MainMenu" ...etc... >
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">To do</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">Notes</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">Settings</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">News</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">Calendar</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">...</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">...</Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">...</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now of course, when a Button in the menu UserControl is clicked, I want to notify the MainWindow that the user wants to navigate. The MainWindow has to change its `CurrentView` property. To show the corresponding view.

The problem I have is that I can't get any communication between components. It seems very hard to achieve this in WPF. There *are* tutorials on the internet, but they are not explaining well enough how to do it the right way.
I think it's a bad idea to just add Click event handlers to each button of the MainMenu. I would like to solve this using commands, and use a command parameter to determine what Button was clicked if that's good practise.

In the most ideal situation, could it be made that the menu just 'emits' something like an event, and that the window catches this? This way the child control (the menu UserControl) wouldn't have to be aware of its parent.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do it. If you are using MVVM, you can just do command binding, if you have lets say ExitApp command in your MainWindow viewmodel,then you can do like this:

```
<vw:ImgButton Name="Exit" ClickCommand="{Binding DataContext.ExitApp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Optionally you can provide info in command parameter and do switching inside ExitApp command as well.

Answer (score 0):

Made a mistake and review my answer. ContextMenu are not in the same "context" and binding are not working easily - I use a Forward command concept so menutiem command are forwarded to the MainViewModel - tell me if you need more, see in my project  [CBR](https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR) and search for ForwardCommand